# How to debug javascript file inside a jar

Tags: java, debugging, web-applications

I have a Java web application that also uses Javascript, all this is contained in a jar file, but I'm having problems with the Javascript code so I want to debug it, is there a way to debug this code while the application is running on a browser?

Comment: Is the javascript cached in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript code runs under browser engine and we can debug by enabling the development tools option in Chrome/firefox browser.

Press F12 key in keyboard to enable developer tools and use addons like Mozilla Firebug